# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This was an assertion made in our textbook but I have no idea how to show that either statement is true.  Also would like to show that that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is strictly larger than $\mathbb{Q}$, which was the second part of the assertion.

Comment: Well, it is clear that it is strictly larger than $\mathbb Q$, as it contains $\mathbb Q$ and it contains $\sqrt 2$.  Are you sure it didn't say "$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ which contains $\sqrt 2$"?

Comment: I think that it might have said something like "the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which contains $\sqrt{2}$", not just "the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$". As for being larger than $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ contains elements which $\mathbb{Q}$ does not. Which ones?

Comment: @Dylan yes you are right title is now corrected. And thanks for the hint

Comment: @lulu How to show it is a subfield, just verify by definition?

Comment: The posted solution gives you the steps to follow. I'd add that the hard one is to see that the multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt 2$ can be written as $c+d\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Maybe something else to note is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ since it is the smallest field of characteristic $0$.  Any ring of characteristic $0$ must contain $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 7):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is *by definition* the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.  The surprising thing (perhaps) is that any element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ can be written in the form $a + b\sqrt{2}$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  To prove this, you have to show the following:

- That the set of all elements of the form $a + b\sqrt{2}$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a field (in other words, that it is closed under addition and multiplication, contains both additive and multiplicative identities, contains additive inverses, and contains multiplicative inverses for all nonzero elements);
- That it contains $\mathbb{Q}$
- That it contains $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is defined as the set of number of the form $p+q\sqrt2$ with $p,q\in \mathbb Q$, it is easy to show it is a field, the only tricky part might be multiplicative inverse, you can use the conjugate for that.

On the other hand any field $F$ that contains $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2$ also contains $q\sqrt2$ with $q$ rational, since $F$ is closed under products and $q$ and $\sqrt2$ belong to $F$. Finally, since $F$ contains every rational $p$ and every number of the form $q\sqrt2$ it contains their sum: $p+q\sqrt2$.

This proves $Q(\sqrt2)\subseteq F$ as desired.

---

Please note it would be unusual for $\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)$ to be defined that way.

Answer (score 1):

Say that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that contains $\sqrt2$ is assume implicitely the ordinary partial order of the set of subsets of $\mathbb C$. Let $K$ be a field such that $K\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$.

If $\sqrt2\in K$ then the set $\sqrt2\mathbb Q$ is not a field because is not closed for the multiplication so we need to take the set $\mathbb Q+\sqrt2\mathbb Q$ in order to have a subfield of $K$ generated by its element $\sqrt2$. But this is the definition of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ so $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another method can be:

We know that if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$ and if $K$ is a finite extension of $F$ then $L$ is a finite extension of $F$ and $[L:F]=[L:K]$ $[K:F]$ .

So suppose there is a field $F$ such that  $\mathbb Q\subseteq F\subseteq\mathbb Q$, then $[F:\mathbb Q] | [\mathbb Q:\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)]$ $\implies$ $[F:\mathbb Q]|2$ .

Now if $[F:\mathbb Q]=1$ then $F=\mathbb Q$

If $[F:\mathbb Q]=2$ $\implies$ $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt2):\mathbb Q]=1$ $\implies$ $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$

So you can see that only subfields of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ are $\mathbb Q$ and  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ therefore your result.