# Why should every stuff belowed be proved in the question that Q(√−3) together with the usual addition and multiplication of real numbers is a field

Tags: linear-algebra

Denote by $\sqrt{−3}$ a square root of $−3$ in $\mathbb C$. Let $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$ denote the set of complex numbers $z$ of the form $z = a + b\sqrt{−3}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Q$. Show that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$ together with the usual addition and multiplication of real numbers is a field.

(Hint: show that for any $w,z\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$ also $w + z, wz, −z$ and $z−1$ are in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$ and that $0$ and $1$ are in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$. Distributivity, commutativity and associativity for addition and multiplication hold in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$ because they hold in $R$.)

I am fine with the procedure of proving this. However, I do not understand why should I prove all the stuff in the Hint?

Could someone please explain to me and give me the reason for each of them e.g. why should I prove that $w+z$ is in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−3})$, which theorem is that.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have a look at the axioms for a subring. In particular, $(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}),+)$ must be an abelian group. Note that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ is a subfield (hence a subring) of $\Bbb C$, but not of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The statement is that something is a field. To prove that, it's enough to verify the *definition* of 'field'.

Comment: It's not so much a theorem as it is a property, it's referred to as closure. You have to show that the result of the ring/field operations remain in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt - 3)$

Comment: Also compare with similar questions, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420471/show-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-is-the-smallest-subfield-of-mathbbc-that-c). [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2868401/mathbbq-sqrt-d-is-the-smallest-subfield-of-mathbbc-containing-math/2868412#2868412) should answer your questions, too.

Comment: @DavidReed The property, that the field operation (say addition) "remains" in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ comes from the axiom that $(Q(\sqrt{-3}),+)$ is supposed to be a group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's generally just considered implicit in the definition of a binary operation, however it frequently needs to be made explicit to people, especially when showing that something is a subring/subfield/subgroup etc.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, exactly. They have to show that addition is "closed", i.e., that $z+w\in K$ for $z,w\in K$. This was one of the questions. The answer is "because it is required by the axioms of a subfield" (and perhaps not so much "as it is a property, it's referred to as closure.")

Answer (score 1):

Well, a field $(K,+,\cdot,0,1)$ consists of two Abelian groups $(K,+,0)$ and $(K^*,\cdot,1)$ such that the operations are linked by distributivity.
Here $K^*= K\setminus\{0\}$.

To show that $({\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{-3}),+,\cdot,0,1)$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C$, it is sufficient to show that $({\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{-3}),+,0)$ and $({\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{-3})^*,+,\cdot,1)$ are subgroups of $({\Bbb C},+,0)$ and $({\Bbb C}^*,\cdot,1)$, respectively.

To show that $U$ is subgroup of $G$ with operation $\circ$, it is sufficient to show that

1) for all $u,v\in U$, $u\circ v\in U$, and

2) for each $u\in U$, the inverse $-u$ or $u^{-1}$ lies in $U$ (depends on whether you write the operation as addition or multiplication).

The other properties will be passed on by the larger structure (group, ring).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I'll change it...

Comment: A field is NOT a group under multiplication.

Comment: A field is not a group under multiplication, but the axioms of a field $K$ in particular require that $(K,+)$ and $(K^{\times},\cdot)$ are abelian groups.

Comment: Right. Clear. Thank you.